# Specify the NoData pixel from 255 to a lower value pixel value

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have a series of raster files (tif) that extracted using a particular shapefile.
However, the output files became much larger (from 2 MB to 200MB). The NoData is now equivalent to pixel value of 255 instead of 0 (maybe this is the reason).

Is there a way to specify it through this code?

```
 import arcpy
 from arcpy import env
 from arcpy.sa import *
 arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
 env.overwriteOutput = True

 #Set the current workspace
 env.workspace = ("C:\Users\Brent\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst and PA")

 #This is for extracting the forest areas of hansen percent treecover
 for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("lossyear*", "TIF"):
     print raster #checking the presence of raster
     outputRasterExtractbyMask = ExtractByMask(raster, "NAMRIA.shp")
     outputRasterExtractbyMask_Name = "forest_only"+raster
     outputRasterExtractbyMask.save(outputRasterExtractbyMask_Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your dataset is larger is not the value of the no data : storing a zero takes the same memory as storing 255. In order to solve your problem, you should make sure that your data is compressed.

```
arcpy.env.compression = "LZ77"
```

and to answer your question,

```
arcpy.env.nodata = "MINIMUM"
```

will set your output to, I cite,

> MINIMUM—The minimum value in the output data range will be used as
>   your NoData value.